# How can I check if sp package (R software) is installed on my Linux and how can I install it?

Tags: r, linux, r-sp

I have installed R on my Linux machine. Whenever I type

```
> library(ps)
```

I get

```
Error in library(ps) : there is no package called ‘ps’
```

How can I check if sp package (R software) is installed on my Linux and how can I install it?

Comment: your code says `ps` but your title and text say "sp".  Are you transposing the letters by accident?

Comment: @Ben Bolker . thank you it seems so. sorry, I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the package is installed in R with `(require(ps))`.
To install the package use `install.packages("ps")`

Comment: when i type 'install.packages("ps")' i get 'Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages("ps") :   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n)'

Comment: @Mohd I suggest that you type 'y' and continue.

Comment: I got this message :package ‘ps’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
it seems that my R is too old? I have just downloaded it ?!?

Comment: There isn't a package called 'ps' on the CRAN repository. Have you heard about this package from someone?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong it is "sp" not ps